# Weird String.getByte(Encoding)

Tags: java, string

I am trying this:

```
byte[] b = String.getBytes("ASCII") and get an UnsupportedEncodingException Exception

String fName = new String(b,"ASCII");

- got the same when used

byte[] b = String.getByte("ISO8859_1");
String fName = new String(b,"ISO8859_1");
```

edit: getByte changed to getBytes

Comment: the question is about **checked exceptions**

Comment: @dfa: I don't think we have enough information to say that. It sounds to me *more* like it's an execution time issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;


public class Encoding
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        String s = "Hello world";
        byte[] b = s.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    }
}
```

Comment: In other words, @andreas, the problem isn't that the code is **throwing** an exception, it's that you're not **catching** one.  Your code wasn't even compiling because you weren't handling that checked exception.

Comment: @Alan M: How did you draw that conclusion? Where does the question say  that the code doesn't compile? Andreas says he "gets" an exception, but not whether it's at execution time or compile time.

Answer (score 7):

That code won't compile - it's `String.getBytes()` not `String.getByte()`, and it's an instance method not a static method. It's always worth cutting and pasting a *real* example which you've got working (even if it's just a dummy app).

However, assuming you've got similar code which *is* compiling, you should be using `"US-ASCII"` and `"ISO-8859-1"` as the names, as documented in the [`Charset` JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

Comment: u r right. it's getBytes. My mistake on the question. Still it does explain why i am getting this exception (other CharSets i tried are US-ASCII)

Comment: The problem with typos in the question is that it's not clear which errors are transcription errors (like getByte/getBytes) and which are *real* errors. Did you *really* have "US-ASCII" or "ASCII"?

Comment: Reminds me of a bug I spent an hour or so trying to figure out.  It turns out that I was calling `new String(bytes, "\"UTF-8\"")`.  The exception message showed the quotes, but of course it didn't click that they were part of the actual encoding name.  Duh!

Comment: FYI, "ASCII" is a valid alias for "US-ASCII".

Comment: @Alan M: It may be on some JREs, but it's not in the list of *guaranteed* ones. It's perfectly possible that andreas' JRE doesn't support that alias.

Answer (score 0):

[according to javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) you must use: `"US-ASCII"`

Answer (score 0):

Although worth noting [this still unresolved bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4623303)...

"**EXPECTED VERSUS ACTUAL BEHAVIOR** :

Ludicrous performance degradation when using encoding
of "US-ASCII" relative to encoding of "ASCII". There is
absolutely no reason why developers should expect such
wildly different performance profiles when executing this
code for these two encodings."

Comment: thanks for the comment Tom, certainly NOT 'worth nothing'. will look into it :)